# Filter according field on array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, nested-attributes

I have an object is **data** like this :

Original data

[image: 1]

const data = {
"title": "sunny",
"members": [
{
"fullname": "rozo",
"customers": [
{
"name": "test11",
"createdAt": 3
},
{
"name": "test12",
"createdAt": 4
},
{
"name": "test13",
"createdAt": 5
}
]
},
{
"fullname": "luffy",
"customers": [
{
"name": "test6",
"createdAt": 9
},
{
"name": "test7",
"createdAt": 10
},
{
"name": "test8",
"createdAt": 11
},
]
}
]
}

I want to filter all customers have create greate than 4 and less than 10, and want to returned result like this :

```
const data = {
    "title": "sunny",
    "members": [
      {
        "fullname": "rozo",
        "customers": [

          {
            "name": "test12",
            "createdAt": 4
          },
          {
            "name": "test13",
            "createdAt": 5
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "fullname": "luffy",
        "customers": [
          {
            "name": "test6",
            "createdAt": 9
          },
          {
            "name": "test7",
            "createdAt": 10
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

**Can anyone help me solve this problem?**

Comment: Please post the actual code **as text** instead of [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). Images can't be copied to create an answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
const filteredData = data.members.map(member => {
    if(member.customers) {    
      return member.customers(customer => {
          if(customer.createdAt >= 4 && customer.createdAt <= 10)
          return customer;
      })
    }
})
```

filteredData would be your final output let me know if you getting any problem

Comment: I has an error : Uncaught TypeError: member.customers is not a function

Comment: That is because you may not have customers for all your members simply add a validation

Answer (score -1):

Use `Array.prototype.filter()`. Define a named function and pass its name (NOT call) to `filter()`:

```js
const memberFilter = e =>
  e.createdAt >= 4 &&
  e.createdAt <= 10;

const filteredMembers = data.members.map(x =>
  x.customers = x.customers.filter(memberFilter)
);

data.members = filteredMembers;
```

`Array.prototype.forEach()` will do the thing in the function to the array in-place and return `undefined`, while `.map()` will copy the array instead and return the copy.

Comment: When I run your code, I has an error :
VM338:41 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createdAt')
    at <anonymous>:41:14
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:40:38

Comment: @Zoro123 I edited this response, please check if the new code works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You could try this solution:

```js
const data = {
  title: 'sunny',
  members: [
    {
      fullname: 'rozo',
      customers: [
        { name: 'test11', createdAt: 3 },
        { name: 'test12', createdAt: 4 },
        { name: 'test13', createdAt: 5 }]
    },
    {
      fullname: 'luffy',
      customers: [
        { name: 'test6', createdAt: 9 },
        { name: 'test7', createdAt: 10 },
        { name: 'test8', createdAt: 11 }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const filteredData = {
  /**
   * MDN documentation on destructuring assignment operator
   * ------------------------------------------------
   * The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.
   *
   * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
   * ------------------------------------------------
   */
  ...data,
  /**
   * MDN documentation on Array.prototype.map()
   * ------------------------------------------------
   * The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
   *
   * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
   * ------------------------------------------------
   */
  members: data.members.map(member => ({
    ...member,
    /**
     * MDN documentation on Array.prototype.filter()
     * ------------------------------------------------
     * The filter() method creates a shallow copy of a portion of a given array, filtered down to just the elements from the given array that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
     *
     * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
     * ------------------------------------------------
     */
    customers: member.customers.filter(customer => customer.createdAt >= 4 && customer.createdAt <= 10)
  }))
};

console.log(filteredData);
```

**Output**

```js
{
  title: 'sunny',
  members: [
    {
      fullname: 'rozo',
      customers: [
        { name: 'test12', createdAt: 4 },
        { name: 'test13', createdAt: 5 }
      ]
    },
    {
      fullname: 'luffy',
      customers: [
        { name: 'test6', createdAt: 9 },
        { name: 'test7', createdAt: 10 }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```